# Tikz draw an accurate angle in a circle

Tags: tikz-pgf

[image]

Here is an illustration in which the angles are not accurately drawn.

I want to know whether there is an easier way to draw an accurate angle within a circle, say `$\angle ABD = 15^\circ$`.

Here is what I have done, from the very beginning:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2]
    \coordinate (O) at (0,0);
    \draw (O) circle (1);
    \coordinate [label=above left:$A$] (A) at (105:1);
    \coordinate [label=below left:$B$] (B) at (225:1);
    \draw (A) -- (B);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

The next steps are draw angles of 15 and 30 degrees from the segment AB, to determine C and D (on the circle).

I wonder if this can be done easily using any Ti*k*Z packages?

Comment: Is this a math or a TikZ problem?

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel This is a TikZ problem. I want to draw this using TikZ. In Maths, we use *compass* and *protractor* to draw this.

Comment: may be used the angles package?  http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/angles-quotes/

Comment: @Nasser That was used to sketch (draw) the graph I posted in OP. But I dont think it can actually draw an accurate angle if I am not mistaken. It only labels the angles.  http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/246856/how-to-label-the-nodes-coordinates-in-tikz-picture/

Answer (score 21, accepted):

For compass and protractor constructions, one can actually just use the `through` library, the `calc` library and the `intersection cs`. The `turn` key can help to find relative polar coordinates.

The `through` library only provides one key which has to be used with a `node`: `circle through`.

It creates a node of the shape circle that has its center at the `at` part of the node and goes through the point given to the key. I am using the point `(right:1)` which is the compass-direction version of `(0:1)` (which is the polar version of `(1, 0)`).

This allows me to create a circle with dimensions that scales with the `scale` value without using `transform shape` or calculating stuff beforehand (which basically is handled by the `through` library). For different `x scale` and `y scale` or other transformations (setting the `x` and/or `y` vector for example) will most likely fail anyway, and you will need to use a `circle`/`ellipse` path operator. However, the `intersection cs` can only work with `circle` nodes and lines (or two lines or two circular nodes). *It really is something for compass and protractors.*

If the circle’s center (as in our example) does not lie on the origin, you will need to use `circle through={([shift={(<center>)}]0:<radius>)}`.

---

The naming of the node `ci` is needed for

- the use with `intersection cs` as it needs the name of a (circular) node and
- the use of its anchor-border where one can use arbitrary angles.

If you don’t use a circular node, instead of `(ci.<angle>)`, you would use `(<angle>:<radius>)` or `([shift={(<center>)}]<angle>:<radius>)`.

---

The points can then be found with:

```
\usetikzlibrary{through, calc} % preamble

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2]
    \coordinate (O) at (0,0);
    \node[draw] (ci) at (O) [circle through=(right:1)] {};
    \coordinate [label=above left:$A$] (A) at (ci.105);
    \coordinate [label=below left:$B$] (B) at (ci.225);
    \path (A) -- (B) -- ([turn]-15:-1) coordinate (B')
          (B) -- (A) -- ([turn]30:-1) coordinate (A');
    \path (intersection cs: first node=ci, second line={(B)--(B')})
      coordinate[label=above:$C$] (C)
          (intersection cs: first node=ci, second line={(A)--(A')})
      coordinate[label=below right:$D$] (D);
    \draw (A) -- (B) -- (C) -- (D) -- cycle [line join=bevel];
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Unfortunately, this is not very accurate when it comes to circles:

[image] [image]

---

The `intersections` library can find intersections between arbitrary paths, not only circles and straight lines. However, a little more work is needed, as path need to be named and the used paths actually need to intersect.

```
\usetikzlibrary{through, intersections} % preamble

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2]
    \coordinate (O) at (0,0);
    \node[draw, name path=ci] (ci) at (O) [circle through=(right:1)] {};
    % or \draw [name path=ci] (O) circle[radius=1];
    \coordinate [label=above left:$A$] (A) at (ci.105);
    \coordinate [label=below left:$B$] (B) at (ci.225);
    \path[overlay] (A) -- (B) -- ([turn]-15:-3) coordinate (B');
    \path[overlay] (B) -- (A) -- ([turn]30:-3) coordinate (A');
    \path[overlay, name path=A] (A) -- (A');
    \path[overlay, name path=B] (B) -- (B');
    \path[name intersections=
      {of=A and ci, by={@,[label=below right:$D$]D}}]; % @ is not used (equals A)
    \path[name intersections={of=B and ci, by={[label=above:$C$]C}}];
    \draw (A) -- (B) -- (C) -- (D) -- cycle [line join=bevel];
\end{tikzpicture}
```

The solution is more correct:

[image]

---

You can also do the calculations beforehand

[image]

and just use TikZ for drawing:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2]
    \coordinate (O) at (0,0);
    \node[draw] (ci) at (O) [circle through=(right:1)] {};
    \coordinate [label=above left:$A$]  (A) at (ci.105);
    \coordinate [label=below left:$B$]  (B) at (ci.225);
    \coordinate [label=      above:$C$] (C) at (ci.225-150);
    \coordinate [label=below right:$D$] (D) at (ci.105-180);
    \draw (A) -- (B) -- (C) -- (D) -- cycle [line join=bevel];
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

Comment: For the first one , it is actually accurate enough but the scale is ruining the precision.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel  Please explain the command `\node[draw] (ci) at (O) [circle through=(right:1)] {};`.  What are you calling `ci`?  You label points on the circumference using it - `\coordinate [label=above left:$A$]  (A) at (ci.105);`, for example.  What does the option `circle through=(right:1)` instruct `TikZ` to draw?

Comment: Thanks! Just realized how easy it is to calculate the angles beforehand. Clearly I was not thinking straight and thought it would be difficult.

Comment: @percusse I don't think. If I use `scale=1` but `2` as the radius for the circle I get the same output. Similar inprecision can be seen with `scale=1` and radius of `1`.

Comment: @Adelyn I've added some explanations. Do they help? The `through` library is explained in the manual.

Comment: It looks like the miter extension to me not the imprecision what you show in the picture. But as scale goes up it starts to get worse.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel  Thanks for the offer.  In such a situation, I would use the `intersections` package.  I am trying to familiarize myself with `TikZ`, and I can do the extra coding needed to use the `intersections` package.

Answer (score 13):

Using the basic geometry of the circle, we can also draw this nicely in [Metapost](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/107489/what-is-metapost-metafont-and-how-can-i-get-started-using-it).

[image]

```
prologues := 3;
outputtemplate := "%j%c.eps";

vardef angle_mark(expr a,b,c,s) =
  fullcircle scaled s rotated angle (a-b) shifted b cutafter (b--c)
enddef;

beginfig(1);

pair A, B, C, D;

path circle;

circle = fullcircle scaled 144;

A = point 2.818 of circle; % a random point on the circle
D = A rotated -30;
B = A rotated (132); % this one can be an arbitrary amount
C = B rotated 60;

label(btex $A$ etex, A scaled 1.1);
label(btex $B$ etex, B scaled 1.1);
label(btex $C$ etex, C scaled 1.1);
label(btex $D$ etex, D scaled 1.1);

dotlabel.bot(btex $O$ etex, origin);

path a[];
a1 = angle_mark(B,A,C,40);
a2 = angle_mark(D,B,A,70);
a3 = angle_mark(B,D,C,40);
draw a1 withcolor .7 white;
draw a2 withcolor .7 white;
draw a3 withcolor .7 white;
label.lrt(btex $30^\circ$ etex scaled 0.6, point 0.3 of a1);
label.top(btex $15^\circ$ etex scaled 0.6, point 0.55 of a2);
label.lrt(btex  $x^\circ$ etex scaled 0.6, point 0.25 of a3);

draw A -- B -- D -- C -- cycle;
draw circle withcolor .67 red;

endfig;
end.
```

The construction relies on the fact that if angle ∠AOD is 30° then ∠ABD=∠ACD=15°, and if angle ∠BOC is 60° then ∠BAC=∠BDC=30°.  The relative rotation from A to B is irrelevant.  It simplifies construction in Metapost to keep the centre at the origin, so that `rotate` can be used in a natural way.

Answer (score 8):

Another MetaPost solution. Thruston was quicker than me for that one :-). My own solution, although following the same basic principles for placing C and D, is a bit different: it uses ready-to-use macros from the [Metafun](http://www.pragma-ade.com/general/manuals/metafun-p.pdf) format to draw the angles (`anglebetween` and `anglelength`) and to place the labels nicely around the circle (`freelabel`). So I thought it could be useful to post it all the same.

Included in a LuaLaTeX program for typesetting convenience:

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{luamplib, gensymb}
  \mplibsetformat{metafun}
  \mplibtextextlabel{enable}
\begin{document}
  \begin{mplibcode}
    u = 3.5cm;
    path circle; circle = fullcircle scaled 2u;
    pair A, B, C, D; 
    A = u*dir 105; 
    B = u*dir 225;
    C = B rotated 60;
    D = A rotated -30;
    beginfig(1);
      draw circle;
      draw A--B--D--C--cycle;
      forsuffixes M = A, B, C, D: freelabel("$" & str M & "$", M, origin); endfor
      anglelength := cm;
      draw anglebetween(A--B, A--C, "$30\degree$");
      draw anglebetween(D--B, D--C, "$x\degree$");
      anglelength := 2cm;
      draw anglebetween(B--A, B--D, "$15\degree$");
    endfig; 
  \end{mplibcode}
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 8):

This solution uses

- the `intercections` library to calculate the intersection of lines AC and BD with the circle.
- the `calc` library for the angles: `($(A)!2!30:(B)$)` meaning `($(A)!<length>!<angle>:(B)$)`. Note: radius is 1, so diameter is 2. That's why a length of 2 will definitely intersect the circle.
- `clip` everything outside the circle.

Code:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,intersections}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2]
        \coordinate[label=above left:$A$] (A) at (105:1);
        \coordinate[label=below left:$B$] (B) at (225:1);
        \draw[name path=circ] (0,0) circle (1);
        \begin{scope}
            \clip (0,0) circle (1);
            \path[name path=AC] (A) -- ($(A)!2!30:(B)$);
            \path[name path=BD] (B) -- ($(B)!2!-15:(A)$);
            \path[name intersections={of=AC and circ, by=C}];
            \path[name intersections={of=BD and circ, by=D}];
            \draw (A) -- (B) -- (D) -- (C) -- cycle;
        \end{scope}
        \node[below right] at (C) {$C$};
        \node[above right] at (D) {$D$};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

**EDIT:** without clipping (as suggested by Heiko Oberdiek)

Without clipping, `line join=bevel` needs to be used. Also a better value than 2 needs to be used as length for the paths AC and BD. 1.2 seems to be a way better choice here.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,intersections}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2]
        \coordinate[label=above left:$A$] (A) at (105:1);
        \coordinate[label=below left:$B$] (B) at (225:1);
        \draw[name path=circ] (0,0) circle (1);
        \path[name path=AC] (A) -- ($(A)!1.2!30:(B)$);
        \path[name path=BD] (B) -- ($(B)!1.2!-15:(A)$);
        \path[name intersections={of=AC and circ, by={[label=below right:$C$]C}}];
        \path[name intersections={of=BD and circ, by={[label=above right:$D$]D}}];
        \draw[line join=bevel] (A) -- (B) -- (D) -- (C) -- cycle;
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**EDIT 2:** set `(A)` to `(130:1)`

If you change the `\path` of AC and BD to `\draw` you can see the actual intersections. So appropriate length values for AC a BD respectively are 1.3 and 1.4. To find intersection C, we need to get the second intersection of AC and circle, so we put a dummy argument as the first intersection:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,intersections}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2]
        \coordinate[label=above left:$A$] (A) at (130:1);
        \coordinate[label=below left:$B$] (B) at (225:1);
        \draw[name path=circ] (0,0) circle (1);
        \path[name path=AC] (A) -- ($(A)!1.4!30:(B)$);
        \path[name path=BD] (B) -- ($(B)!1.3!-15:(A)$);
        \path[name intersections={of=AC and circ, by={dummy,[label=below right:$C$]C}}];
        \path[name intersections={of=BD and circ, by={[label=above right:$D$]D}}];
        \draw[line join=bevel] (A) -- (B) -- (D) -- (C) -- cycle;
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: There is an alternative for clipping here: `line join=bevel`.

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek Clipping also clips the paths AC and BD. But choosing a more reasonable value than 2 for the length of those paths will solve this too. Made an edit.

Comment: If I change the position of $A$ to `(A) at (130:1)`. I got a wired result, of which the position of $C$ is in the circle, even after I change the `length` key.

Comment: @ChenStatsYu In the case of `(A) at (130:1)` you'll need the second intersection of AC and circ. So use a dummy as the first intersection. See my edit.

Comment: From this Figura, how to paint the area of  inscribed angles ACD?

Comment: @benedito `\fill[red] (A) -- (C) -- (D);`